# Grammaticality: 'gift ... will not be denied him' (1786 UK)

Tags: grammaticality, eighteenth-century-english, ditransitivity

[Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CCkvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22He+speaks+not+of+such+as+have+vowed+Chastity%22&source=bl&ots=1Ff1KL_aEw&sig=g_JuLG-41yB6k5KxqW2ZCmmApak&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cAzgVNuQJomcNtydgQg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22He%20speaks%20not%20of%20such%20as%20have%20vowed%20Chastity%22&f=false): p 174, *The Catholic Christian Instructed in the Sacraments* ...,  by [Richard Challoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Challoner), 1786

> A. Continency is not required of all, but such as 
>   have by vow engaged to keep it: and therefore, before 
>   a person engages himself by vow, he ought certainly to 
>   examine whether he has a call from God, and whether 
>   he can go through with what he thinks of undertaking : 
>   but after he has once engaged himself by vow, he is 
>   not now at liberty to go back: but may assure himself, 
>   that `the gift of continence` will not be **denied him**, so 
>   that he uses proper means to obtain and preserve it, 
>   particularly prayer and mortification
>
> [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deny?q=deny):
>
> 3.  [3.1] deny somebody something ... [3.2.] deny `something` to somebody

I recognise radical differences between 1700s and modern grammar, but should the above follow the ditransitive syntax 3.2? Here, `something` = `the gift of continence`, functions as the subject of the relative clause. So as per 3.2, should the bolded be written instead as '**denied TO him**' ?

Footnote: I lit on this work only while reading [definition c. for 'to vow' on OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/224758?rskey=OTzz9x&result=2&isAdvanced=false).

Answer (score 4):

Just as you can **give *people* things**, so too can you **deny *people* things**. Sure, you could give things ***to*** people but you don’t have to do it that way: you can just give them whatever. Similarly, you can also deny them whatever. Or, if it’s your sweetheart on Valentine’s day, you might do well to deny them nothing. :)

Any dictionary deserving of that name should have covered this, considering that it’s a basic feature of English — and of lots of other related languages, too. It’s nothing fancier than a simple indirect object use, which happens all the time with English verbs.

The OED provides these historical citations for *deny* use ditransitively:

> - C. 1340 *Cursor M.* 1586 (Fairf.) ― He wende þat god of miȝt walde deny ham heyuen briȝt.
> - 1576 Gascoigne *Philomene* (Arb.) 95 ― To denay His own deare child and sonne in lawe The thing that both did pray.
> - 1593 Shaks. 2 *Hen. VI*, ɪ. iii. 107 ― Then let him be denay’d the Regent-ship.
> - 1649 H. Lawrence *Some Considerat*. 36 ― No man that considers the premises will deny me this, That [etc.].
> - 1652 Needham tr. *Selden’s Mare Cl*. 3 ― It is unjust to denie Merchants or Strangers the benefit of Port, Provisions, Commerce, and Navigation.
> - 1814 D’Israeli *Quarrels Auth*. (1867) 424 ― All the consolations of fame were denied him during his life.
> - 1863 H. Cox *Instit*. ɪɪɪ. vii. 701 ― Parliament was denied its proper control over an important branch of public expenditure.

Although Shakespeare did a lot of denying people things, both in his plays and his poetry, this is not an archaic usage. People still get denied things today. You can be denied admission to a show, and if you are, then someone has denied you admission to that show.

Comment: Right. _Deny_ is a ditransitive verb, and it participates in the Dative Alternation. I.e, _I denied permission to him_ is equivalent to (and just as grammatical as) _I denied him permission_; if you substitute _give_ for _deny_, you get the same pattern.  And Passive can apply either with or without Dative Alternation, producing both _The gift was denied/given to him_ and _He was denied/given the gift_. 200 years ago, the _to_ in _The gift was denied **to** him_ was deletable; nowadays I'm not so sure. It sounds wrong to me.